# Issue occurred When UISearchController used under LargeNavigation Bar in iOS 11

Tags: android, ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

When I add Search controller in my Large navigation bar and after that when I touch on it then it displays some unknown space between navigation bar and my tablview controller **which is what I describe in my GIF with the red line.** and also it's working perfectly when I set navigation bar **isTranslucent = true** Has anyone an Idea about that ?

***Please Click on the Image it's a GIF***

Thanks in advance.

**and this is my code**

```
    let searchbar = searchController.searchBar
    searchbar.delegate = self
    searchbar.tintColor = UIColor.white
    searchbar.barTintColor = UIColor.white

    searchController.definesPresentationContext = true

    //textColor
    UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).defaultTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]

    //placeholder color
    UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Search user", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])


    //background color
    if let textfield = searchbar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
        if let backgroundview = textfield.subviews.first {

            // Background color
            backgroundview.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 49.0/255.0, green: 49.0/255.0, blue: 49.0/255.0, alpha: 0.6)

            // Rounded corner
            backgroundview.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
            backgroundview.clipsToBounds = true;
        }
    }

    //navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic
```

**and also attached GIF**

[image]

Comment: self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false, add this line in viewDidLoad() method, check it.

Comment: @AshokPolu it's not working.